# Is there a more efficient way I could handle variables when collecting data from input in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am collecting first names, and last names in order to gather a persons full name.

I know I could do so by:

```
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string fullname;

    cout << "Users firstname ? "; cin >> firstname;
    cout << "Users last name ? "; cin >> lastname;

    fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
```

In python I could just:

```
first_name = input("What is your first name?")
```

Doing this is nice because it provides the initialization of the variable and assignment of the value in one line.

Is there a way that I can use the same design within C++ to reduce redundancy in my code?

Comment: Perhaps consider reading full lines (`std::getline( std::cin, firstname )`) since multiple first-/lastnames are a thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a C++ version of [`input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and use it. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

std::string input() {
    std::string line;
    if(getline(std::cin, line))
        return line;
    throw std::runtime_error(std::cin.eof() ? "end of input" : "input error");
}

std::string input(char const* prompt) {
    (std::cout << prompt).flush();
    return input();
}

int main() {
    auto firstname = input("Enter first name? ");
    auto lastname = input("Enter last name? ");
    auto fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
    std::cout << "Hello " << fullname << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think you can get rid of one of the variables easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string lastname;
std::string fullname;

std::cout << "Users firstname ? "; std::cin >> fullname;
std::cout << "Users last name ? "; std::cin >> lastname;

fullname += ' ' + lastname;

std::cout << "Full name: " << fullname << std::endl;

return 0;
```

}

The second way as you desired with iterators is more of what you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Users firstname ? ";
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(std::cin);

    std::string fullName;

    std::cout << "Users lastname ? ";
    fullName += *it;
    ++it;
    fullName += ' ' + *it;

    std::cout << "Full Name: " << fullName << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Personally I think the first way is easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 0):

There was an interesting [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/gtzsnm/we_need_to_do_better_than_cin_for_new_programmers/) that covered this topic with the example you showed.

Currently, C++ has no standard way of achieving the same, but the author of said post provided a [header-only library](https://github.com/ShakaUVM/read) (meaning that you can just copy paste the code in your file / a file in your project or simply include the dependency) which does this, e.g.:

```
int age = read<int>("Please enter your age: ");
cout << "You are " << age << " years old.\n";
```

---

If you are not interested in applying external dependencies, you have to stick with the standard solutions, i.e., what you have showed in your question and what was shown in **Eddie C.**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901585/7151494).